# How to partition my hard drive(Samsung)

Tags: partitioning, samsung

Just got my Samsung NP305V5A-A04US(actually finally made the jump thanks to crackout12)

Booted it up a Samsung app popped up after creating password. The app wanted to partition my drive, didn't know what to do at the time and had to go so I shut it off. Booted it back up and it just went straight into installing windows. Now I do not know how to partition it. Searched through programs and files. I thought it was called Easy Partition or something like that but guess not. When I enter partition it brings up Disk Management no idea what to do. Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 1):

#### To your first question:

Yes, you should partition your drive. At least a small partition for swap space - rule of thumb: 2 times your real RAM - should be made, at least for hibernation this is recommended.

Select linux/swap as partition type.

For a desktop system, this might be enough, but a seperate /home partition is often seen. It might be handsome for backup images.

#### 2nd and 3rd Question:

You don't need to download drivers. Drivers are included in the kernel. But you shouldn't, as an unexperienced user, install a beta version. You may install 11.10 and upgrade in April easily.

Answer (score 0):

:)
Well, SAMSUNG default partition includes 3 primary partitions;
@100MB~ for Windows Loader.
@Big partition for Windows 7 system.
@Medium partition for backup.

Hard drives can only get up to 4 primary partitions. An extended partition counts as a primary, but it can include multiple logical partitions. So, in order to maintain your 3 default partitions, use the Ubuntu setup to resize the main and big Windows 7 primary partition, and then make an extended partition on the remaining size. On the extended partition, you can have 3 setups deppending on your needings, if you think that you might need to move the Ubuntu System partition to another sector on the hard drive, a /boot partition is reccommended. If you need to share your /home partition with other Linux distros, you need one. If not, you only need a root / partition, and, as said by @user unknown, a swap partition is reccomended.

Using the last stable release, (11.10), is the most reccomended. But you need either a Minimal ISO to get Ubuntu running on the A-Series APU, or a 12.04 build (beta1 recommended).

Good luck, and don´t forget to ask! ;)